# Instead of a Label for a Node or an Edge, Id like to add an ICON

Tags: cytoscape.js, cytoscape

When looking at CytoscapeJs, i was noticing that a lot of the labels was accomplished by strings.  Some sort of naming mechanism, but if i wanted to instead, say show a warning Icon for the Label of an EDGE or prepend a ICON to the existing Label for a Name, it seems there is nothing really to account for that.

I was looking at using things like unicode characters to define what is to be presented, but I have noticed 2 things.  Depending on your level of zoom, the character would be a black rectangle, and also the characters are in some cases limited to the OS and Browser language packs.

I wanted to just be able to define an icon image, or use ionicons or something else to add this.

Note:  I was also looking at the npm package:  ctyoscape-node-label-html, which manages to encapsulate a Node with html, but it too has issues.  1.  The package is called cytoscape-NODE-label-html and makes no mention in the documentation as to EDGE labels.  2.  The last release was over 2 years ago, so i was thinking that maybe it meant that cytoscapejs has updated to the point where it has implemented the ability to add icons.

In the Commom Use cases of IonIcons, it usually just adds items based on class references, so i was thinking i might be able to add the classes and it would work without even touching the label, but i havent had much success.

Is there something i am missing with regard to Cytoscape?  I have not seen any demos on their website, so being able to supply demos with how this would work would be fantastic.

I dont personally have any code at the moment, but one can use pretty much any of the sample cytoscapejs samples ( https://js.cytoscape.org/ ) as a jumping off platform for this Iconography.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a demo code that uses icons from`IonIcons`. Unfortunately, I have to use embedded SVG code for use in this demonstration, so that, I can manipulate it as needed.

```js
// airplane.svg source: 
// https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ionic-team/ionicons/main/docs/ionicons/svg/ios-airplane.svg
function airplane_mkr(fill_color,rot_angle) {
let airplane = '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="80" height="50"  viewBox="0 0 512 512"><g transform="rotate(rot_angle,256,256)"><path fill="fill_color" d="M407.7 224c-3.4 0-14.8.1-18 .3l-64.9 1.7c-.7 0-1.4-.3-1.7-.9L225.8 79.4c-2.9-4.6-8.1-7.4-13.5-7.4h-23.7c-5.6 0-7.5 5.6-5.5 10.8l50.1 142.8c.5 1.3-.4 2.7-1.8 2.7L109 230.1c-2.6.1-5-1.1-6.6-3.1l-37-45c-3-3.9-7.7-6.1-12.6-6.1H36c-2.8 0-4.7 2.7-3.8 5.3l19.9 68.7c1.5 3.8 1.5 8.1 0 11.9l-19.9 68.7c-.9 2.6 1 5.3 3.8 5.3h16.7c4.9 0 9.6-2.3 12.6-6.1L103 284c1.6-2 4.1-3.2 6.6-3.1l121.7 2.7c1.4.1 2.3 1.4 1.8 2.7L183 429.2c-2 5.2-.1 10.8 5.5 10.8h23.7c5.5 0 10.6-2.8 13.5-7.4L323.1 287c.4-.6 1-.9 1.7-.9l64.9 1.7c3.3.2 14.6.3 18 .3 44.3 0 72.3-14.3 72.3-32S452.1 224 407.7 224z"/></g></svg>';
  airplane = airplane.replace("fill_color", fill_color);
  airplane = airplane.replace("rot_angle", rot_angle);
  const svg_Url = encodeURI("data:image/svg+xml;utf-8," + airplane);
  return {"background-color":"#bbbbbb", "background-image":svg_Url, label:"data(name)", width:60, height:60, opacity:1.0};

}
//Colored/rotated airplanes icons
const pink_plane = airplane_mkr("pink","135");
const green_plane = airplane_mkr("green","90");
const gold_plane = airplane_mkr("gold","45");
const blue_plane = airplane_mkr("blue","60");
const red_plane = airplane_mkr("red","180");

var cy = cytoscape({
  container: document.getElementById("cy"),

  elements: {
    nodes: [
      {
        data: { id: "j", name: "France" },
        position: { x: 100, y: 100 },
        classes: "FRA"
      },
      {
        data: { id: "e", name: "SVG Icon" },
        position: { x: 100, y: 500 },
        classes: "SVG"
      },
      {
        data: { id: "k", name: "Italy" },
        position: { x: 600, y: 500 },
        classes: "italy"
      },
      {
        data: { id: "g", name: "The Netherlands" },
        position: { x: 550, y: 80 },
        classes: "netherlands"
      }
    ],

    edges: [
      { data: { source: "j", target: "e", label: "JE" } },
      { data: { source: "j", target: "g", label: "JG" } },
      { data: { source: "e", target: "j" } },
      { data: { source: "k", target: "j" } },
      { data: { source: "k", target: "e", label: "KE" } },
      { data: { source: "k", target: "g" } },
      { data: { source: "g", target: "j" } }
    ]
  },

  style: [
    {
      selector: "node.FRA",
      style: pink_plane
    },
    {
      selector: "node.SVG",
      style: green_plane
    },
    {
      selector: "node.italy",
      style: gold_plane
    },
    {
      selector: "node.netherlands",
      style: blue_plane
    },
    {
      selector: "node.FRA",
      style: red_plane
    },

    {
      selector: "edge",
      style: {
        label: "data(label)",
        width: 3,
        "line-color": "#c0c",
        "target-arrow-color": "#00c",
        "curve-style": "bezier",
        "target-arrow-shape": "triangle",
        "target-arrow-fill": "#c00",
        "arrow-scale": 20
      }
    },
    {
      selector: ".highlight",
      css: {
        "background-color": "yellow"
      }
    }
  ],
  layout: {
    name: "preset"
  }
});
```

```css
#cy {
    width: 800px;
    height: 400px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    left: 5px;
}
ion-icon {
  font-size: 64px;
  color: blue;
  --ionicon-stroke-width: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script type="module" src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@5.5.2/dist/ionicons/ionicons.esm.js"></script>
<script nomodule src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@5.5.2/dist/ionicons/ionicons.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cytoscape/2.7.10/cytoscape.min.js"></script>
<div>
<span>Some ionicon icons</span><br/>
<ion-icon name="airplane" size="small"></ion-icon> <!--filled-->
<ion-icon name="airplane-sharp" size="large"></ion-icon> <!--sharp-->
<ion-icon name="airplane-outline"></ion-icon> <!--outline-->
</div><br/>
<div id="cy"></div>
```

Comment: So, Cytoscape doesnt actually support ICONS at this point in time.  Now the issue you have is that you need to have a function which would encapsulate the SVG for every possible icon you would want to do.  This createa a lot of needless bloat instead of assigning classes etc.

Not saying this is bad as it shows how you can do something like this, but if i wanted to change an icon i would need to update the svg so it isnt as easy unless you can dynamically pull the svg from node or some other mechanism to make it more dynamic. Since it is an embed, i never need ionicons.

Comment: I will give you +1 because you have a way to do it by using the icon svg, but it is very much so hardcoded, not dynamic, and doesnt let you do it through class assignment.

Comment: @Fallenreaper Can you ask as a new question using my answer as a reference explaining why the current situation needs improvement and ask for ways to achieve them.

Comment: Currently following the Cytoscape Repo with the issue being tracked.  It is going to be implemented soon, and will be available as a part of a newer release.  I dont plan to give updates to this question until the update is pushed to prod and documented.